# Multiple boxplots from conditions on a single variable

Tags: r

I am looking for simplified way to create multiple boxplots from conditions on a single variable in Base R. I know how to do this by creating a new column and using a formula, but would like a way to do it solely within the boxplot() function (i.e. in one step) if possible.

For instance, say my data looks like:

```
     R BatAge
1  614   26.8
2  602   27.9
3  613   27.8
4  654   29.3
5  685   29.4
6  707   29.9
7  855   30.1
8  752   29.3
9  716   28.6
10 703   29.7
11 789   30.1
12 724   31.3
13 706   30.2
14 777   30.7
15 764   30.8
16 747   31.2
17 831   30.1
18 687   29.4
19 772   29.0
20 693   28.3
```

Is it possible for me to separate the 'R' column into two boxplots based on whether or not BatAge < 30 by just using the boxplot() function and not having to create a variable that sorts them beforehand?

Comment: But if the two categories are < 30 and > 30, what is the continuous y-variable? Year would not make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to cut this down and communicate clearly what I was looking for and included the wrong variable of interest. I have edited it to reflect. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, and the best way is to create a new variable: `overThirty <- factor(BatAge >= 30)`. Use this for plotting (`boxplot(R ~ overThirty)`).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am already doing it that way. I am just wondering if there is a way to do it within the arguments of boxplot() alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
boxplot(R ~ BatAge > 30, data = df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even think about using a conditional in the formula! I wound up being able to take this and use an ifelse() along with it to get more interesting labels than T/F.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use some function outside of `boxplot` to generate a categorical variable.

One way in base R using `Hmisc::cut2`, assuming data frame named `mydata`:

```
boxplot(R ~ Hmisc::cut2(BatAge, 30), mydata)
```

[image]

Or using `dplyr::mutate()`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(Group = ifelse(BatAge >= 30, "High", "Low")) %>% 
  boxplot(R ~ Group, .)
```